# Unrestricted File Upload Vulnerability, any solution?

Tags: injection

I have a module in which the user can upload images. So I run some test, via tamper data I can change it from .png to .php and it will upload successfully on my server but if I go to the location it appears "Not found". So what do you think is an attacker still able to do something with that or not?

Answer (score 0):

There might be cases when the file can be executed, it depends on many factors, code, server setup, etc.

First of all you should

- Do a MIME check on the uploaded data
- Restrict extensions to common picture extensions

Comment: The question was: So what do you think is an attacker still able to do something with that or not?

Comment: The suggestion here is reasonable and prudent.  If the rest of your set-up employs good security, then reasonable and prudent will work most of the time.  One cannot ask for 100% security.

Answer (score -1):

**So what do you think is an attacker still able to do something with that or not?**

If you:

1. Try to change the .png to .php and you get "Not found" then that means there is no fille with .php extetion on that specific link (it doesn't mean you can't).
2. Try to see if you can upload a file of .php extensions instead of a file with .png extensions you should try other methods (because you can't change the file just by requesting a different extension to the server)

**How to check an upload form:**

Read this OWASP document: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried other extensions for example: .cer , .asp , phtml , .php5 but when I go to the upload path it says: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
Only for .php files it appears Not found, so what do you think is an attacker still able to upload for e.g. shell? Btw my site is based on ruby and javascript.

Comment: If it's written in Ruby, why are you trying to upload PHP? Also, what framework are you using? It probably won't even execute arbitrary uploaded Ruby files.

Comment: @korockinout13 I'm using Ruby on rails and some other js frameworks.